# PHP PDO prepare statement failure

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I've been having a failure when I want to submit data for my database.
The connection is established, but when I use:

```
 $sql = $MyConnection->prepare("
    INSERT INTO AMP_USERS (Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$lastname', '$email')
    ");

  $sql->execute();
```

I get a failure.
I've already done:

```
$sql->bindParam(:username, $username)
```

And so on, but that didn't work / didn't provide the error.
Somehow the data doesn't gets stored into the database, and the error must be somewhere in this bit of code.

**EDIT**

Though I don't think all of the code is necessary I'll post it:

```
    <?php

  require('config.php');

  if($MyConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=fdb6.biz.nf;dbname=1446018_venator', $dbusername, $dbpassword)) {
    echo "A connection has been made!";
  }

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  // Hasing the password:
  // A higher "cost" is more secure but consumes more processing power
  $cost = 10;

  // Create a random salt
  $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

  // Prefix information about the hash so PHP knows how to verify it later.
  // "$2a$" Means we're using the Blowfish algorithm. The following two digits are the cost parameter.
  $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;

  // Hash the password with the salt
  $hash = crypt($password, $salt);

  $sql = $MyConnection->prepare("
    INSERT INTO AMP_USERS (Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES (:username, :password, :lastname, :email)
    ");
  $sql->bindParam(':username', $username);
  $sql->bindParam(':password', $hash);
  $sql->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
  $sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
  $sql->execute();

?>
```

Comment: You have no parameters in your statement to which to bind variables. You have directly inserted `$username` etc into the query, where you should be using parameter placeholders like `:username`

Comment: How have you configured PDO to report errors? By default it treats them silently.

Comment: Please read the whole question. I have already stated that I've used that method. I was wondering if that could've caused a problem (as I may have been using it wrong, but that's not the case).

Comment: I did read the whole question, and as worded it implies you attempted to bind parameters to the query _as written_, which would be in error.

Comment: I can't completely follow you. And no I've not configured PDO to report errors, as I'm still learning PDO.

Both ways should not give any problems in my eyes. If I use bindParam, or simply directly insert $username it shouldn't give any errors. So where would my problem be?

Comment: To avoid this dull conversation, PLEASE POST EXACT COMPLETE CODE you run. All in the question body, not in comments. Along with CERTAIN definition of "failure"

Comment: Error reporting will tell you what the problem is. It could be, for example, that your connection in `$MyConnection` isn't even properly established.  Read over http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I'm already using an if-statement and an echo to see if the connection works. And as I stated, the connection works fine.

Comment: It is not about "all" but about **actual**. Your second code is essentially different from one you posted at first.

Comment: That's because I changed it back. Furthermore, it shouldn't give any errors in solving the problem, because both ways (OP and Edited code did not work).

Comment: @JesseDijkstra Creating a new PDO object via `new PDO()` will not return `FALSE` on failure. It will return a PDO object in an error state, so your containing `if()` statement will not tell you anything about its state; the object itself is always truthy even if broken and your success message will always print.  Read over the PDO doc examples on how to establish a connection with error checking in a try/catch.

Comment: Follow the examples here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: ... actually it would throw a fatal exception if broken. Something else is wrong, like incorrect permission to the table or any number of things. You need to check `errorInfo()` as documented.

Comment: I've used your method @MichaelBerkowski, but did not get an error echoed out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Failing but not reporting an error

Change `PDO`'s error reporting.

```
$MyConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

If there is an SQL error, PDO should report it now.

### Select the Database

The only error I see in your query other than possible errors caused by variable interpolation is that the table name is not fully qualified.  If you have not selected the DB already, it may need to be.

```
$MyConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME");
// or in the query
"INSERT INTO DBNAME.AMP_USERS ..."
```

***Note*** that you would not literally write `DBNAME` but rather what the actual name of your database is.

### Use Prepared Statements

You should do this regardless to protect against injection, but based on the contents of the variables you are using, they may be causing problems as well.

```
$stmt = $MyConnection->prepare("
    INSERT INTO AMP_USERS (Username, Password, Lastname, Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
");
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password, $lastname, $email));
```

Using named parameters like `$stmt->execute(array(":username" => $username))` or using `$stmt->bindParam(":username", $username)` (or `bindValue`) is also valid.

---

If these explanations do not help you solve your problem you have omitted important data from your question.

Comment: I've given some more information regarding my code. Maybe that'll help?

Comment: Finally! I start to get errors!
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '1446018_venator.AMP_USERS' doesn't exist' in /srv/disk3/1446018/www/askmephilosophy.co.nf/register.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk3/1446018/www/askmephilosophy.co.nf/register.php(38): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in

Comment: @JesseDijkstra that should answer your question; does the DB user have the correct grants on this table?

Comment: Oh God, I'm gonna hate myself for this. Apparently I simply misspelled the table name. Instead of AMP_USERS I should have spelled AMP_Users.
Thanks for the answer and help!